# What's the bias of calculating the Kendall coefficient of correlation on a sample instead of a whole population?

Tags: correlation, bias, kendall-tau

I am trying to calculate Kendall coefficient of correlation but my data frame in R contains 6 million observations and 17 variables. It is numerically hard for R to compute the estimator on a whole data frame so I tried to compute this on a sample of 1000 observations.

What's the bias of this estimator? What's the loss of information?

Is a rational way of dealing with this problem to resample (let's say 100/1000 times), evaluating the coefficient on sample sizes of 1000, and then taking their mean to find a final coefficient?

Comment: Kendall correlation uses just very simple operations - what is your problem with sample size? I imagine it may be time consuming but I don't see any reason why this should not work with a big sample size. As this is just comparing pairs, I imagine this could be coded in MapReduce framework to work with data that does not fit into computer memory at all. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kendall_tau_rank_correlation_coefficient

Comment: I sometimes wonder why it's not on Hive yet if this is so easy to be coded. It should compare pairs but somehow I think they should be ordered first to make it faster. Each with each is n^2 ?

Comment: See the wiki page, it reviews few algorithms that could be used or adapted for your purposes.

Comment: Yes there is some sort algorithm with n*logn :)

Comment: But how long does it take with your data? Hours? I doubt it is days... You could also think of implementing those algorithms to work in parallel to speed things up.

Comment: Bootstrap as Jakub mentioned in an accepted answer seems to be easier to use :)

Comment: If downsampling is ok for you, then why not. However in many (most?) cases you'd prefer to use full sample even if it took a little bit longer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if you are really interested in assessing the bias of the estimator or rather (more generally) its uncertainty? IMO more common approach - bootstrapping - will be suitable for this task.

Sampling many subsamples with replacement and calculating the estimator value for each sampled chunk of data will give you bootstrap distribution of the estimator, from which you can perform further inference about its uncertainty using bootstrap confidence intervals.

Choosing sample size and the number of bootstrap samples is up to you, but as usual: the more, the better.

*Update:* Here you can find more details on this method: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_%28statistics%29#Deriving_confidence_intervals_from_the_bootstrap_distribution . So you just have to calculate the estimates in each sample and then the desired percentiles from the obtained distribution.

Comment: Can You tell maybe how can I calculate the confidence interval for bootstrap sample or post any link about that (by upadating post)? Thanks or answer. I ment something like bootstrap when I mentioned resampling. Sure I'm rather concerned about uncertainty:) thanks!